# Moment: avoiding reference

Tags: javascript, reference, momentjs

I want to receive an array of moment objects, based on start / and date.
I wrote the following code in which the first start date is 27/12/2014:

```
    _calculateDateInterval: function(date_start, date_end){ 
        var current = date_start.startOf("day"); 
        var arr_dates = []; 
        var i = 1; 

        while(date_end.startOf("day").diff(current, "days") > 0){ 
            var copy_current = $.extend({}, current); //Clone the object without reference 
            console.log(copy_current); 
            arr_dates.push(copy_current); 
            current.add(1, "days"); 
            //Break the loop for testing purposes
            i++; 
            if(i == 2){ 
                return false; 
            }; 
        }; 
        return arr_dates; 
    },
```

There is a problem though. Even when checking only on the first loop, the console gives me the following log:
[image]

This is confusing; when opening the dropdown, _d shows another day than when it is collapsed.
In order to store the right moment object, I need to remove the reference to the original (current) Moment object of which the day is increased on each loop. (In this case I need 27/12/2014, not the value including the day increase).

Any (better) suggestions?

Comment: Pay no attention to `_d`.  Use the formatting functions instead.  Underscored properties are meant to be treated as internal.

Answer (score 0):

Found it already in the docs:

> All moments are mutable. If you want a clone of a moment, you can do
>   so explicitly or implicitly.
>
> Calling moment() on a moment will clone it.